# How to arrange functions in increasing order of growth rate , providing f(n)=O(g(n))

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Given the following functions i need to arrange them in increasing order of growth 
a) $2^{2^n}$
b) $2^{n^2}$
c) $n^2 \log n$
d) $n$
e) $n^{2^n}$
My first attempt was to plot the graphs but it didn't gave the correct answer so I took a look on [How do I determine the increasing order of growth of a set of functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121366/how-do-i-determine-the-increasing-order-of-growth-of-a-set-of-functions)
and calculated the log for all the functions listed above and got

a) $2^{2^n} \Rightarrow 2^n + \log 2$ 
b) $2^{n^2} \Rightarrow n^2 + \log 2$ 
c) $n^2 \log n \Rightarrow 2\log n + \log \log n$ 
d) $n \Rightarrow \log n$ 
e) $n^{2^n} \Rightarrow 2^n + \log n$

and then i plotted them on graph and got the answer : dcbea
but when i submitted the answer it seems to be incorrect.
What i am doing wrong?

Comment: You might find [this MathJax tutoral](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) handy in future :)

Comment: Your log for a) b) and e) is wrong, it's a multiplication, not an addition

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut, i applied your suggestion and got dcabe, but it's still incorrect

Comment: Maybe you have not plotted on a wide enough range, or you mistyped your function. You order is correct except **a** and **b** must be switched, which is obvious, since $2^n$ grows much faster than $n^2$. And $2^n > n^2$ for any $n>4$.

Comment: Even with the flawed logs computed in the question, one reaches the correct order (which is not dcbea).

Comment: OP: Are you really supposed to "solve" this by plotting functions? Plots will prove nothing...

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Are you suggesting that switching a and b in dcbea yields the correct answer?

Comment: @Did No, in **dcabe**, I was refering to sol4me's answer to my comment.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I see, thanks.

Comment: @DidNo, The correct answer is dcbae. I plotted the graph(link in answer) and tried to look the fxns behavior as n increases. If you know some better way then please share, i will be glad to know.

Comment: @sol4me Graphs are no method at all, at most they can provide an *indication* of what is going on. "Better way"? Sure, to do the maths, as in Jean-ClaudeArbaut's answer for example. (Unrelated: Typing `@DidNo` (no space) makes that your comment is not signaled to me.)

Comment: @DidNo Thanks!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer @sol4me *If you know some better way then please share, i will be glad to know.*

First, never trust a plot. You just saw it may hurt, so even if it *can* help, it's not a proof.

Then, you must know some basic comparison scales, for example, as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and fixed $a>0, b>0, c>1$ and any real $d$,

$$d \ll \log \log n \ll \log^a n \ll n^b \ll c^n \ll n! \ll n^n$$

Where I write $a_n \ll b_n$ iff $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \rightarrow 0$ (this is **not** a standard notation !)

Of course, there are many other possible asymptotic comparisons, these are just the most frequent.

You have also some allowed operations, for example,

- if $\xi>1$ is a fixed real and $1 \ll a_n \ll b_n$, then $\xi^{a_n} \ll \xi^{b_n}$.
- if $s_n \ll a_n$ and $s_n \ll b_n$, and if $a_n \ll b_n$, then $a_n + s_n \ll b_n + s_n$.

You prove such things by computing the limit. Taking $\log$ as you did may be very useful (for example in the first case above).

Finally, you have to apply these comparisons to your case, and sometimes it's a bit tricky, but honestly here it's not.

- $n^2 \ll 2^n$ so $2^{n^2} \ll 2^{2^n}$
- $2 \ll n$, so $2^{2^n} \ll
     n^{2^n}$. If in doubt, write the quotient
  $a_n=\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^{2^n}$, and since
  $\frac{2}{n}<\frac{1}{2}$ as soon as $n>4$, you have $a_n \rightarrow
     0$
- $1 \ll \log n $, so $n^2 \ll n^2 \log n$, and since $n \ll n^2$, you have $n \ll n^2\log n$.
- $n \ll n^2$ so $2^n \ll 2^{n^2}$, and also $\log n \ll n$ so $n^2 \log n \ll n^3$. Then $n^3 \ll 2^n$, hence $n^2\log n \ll n^3 \ll 2^n \ll 2^{n^2}$, and especially $n^2 \log n \ll 2^{n^2}$.

When you have a doubt, write what the comparison means as a limit, and compute the limit.

And remember, these comparisons are *asymptotic*. Sometimes the smallest $n$ such that the inequality really holds may be *very* large, but it's nevertheless only a fixed, finite number. You may have inequality for $n> 10^{10^{10}}$ for example, so trying to plot things is often hopeless.

If you want to know more about such methods, there are good readings, such as *Concrete Mathematics*, by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jean-Claude Arbaut mentioned, the problem was in calculating log.
To summarize we need to first calculate the log for all the functions and then plot them for **wide range of number**. I plotted it [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o6xayq51ff)

Comment: I followed your advice with a similar problem and got the right answer, but I don't ger why. How is plotting f(n) different from log(f(n))? Does it have to do with how log(n) behaves with wide ranges?

Comment: Yes, In general plotting graph in some cases might give you the right answer but the functions can behave differently on wider ranges.